Spring Boot Application Fails to Create/Replace ConfigMap in Minikube After Upgrade
I have a Spring Boot application running locally that interacts with a Minikube cluster. The application uses the Fabric8 Kubernetes Client to manage Kubernetes resources such as ConfigMaps. The application was working fine previously, but after upgrading the environment, it fails when attempting to create or replace a ConfigMap using createOrReplaceConfigMap.
Here is the relevant snippet of the code:
private ConfigMap createOrReplaceConfigMap(String resourceName, Map<String, Object> config) throws JsonProcessingException {
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> configData = new HashMap<>();
for (Object key : config.keySet()) {
    configData.put((String) key, om.writeValueAsString(config.get(key)));
}

ConfigMap configMap = new ConfigMapBuilder()
    .withMetadata(
        new ObjectMetaBuilder().withName(resourceName).withNamespace("my-namespace").build())
    .withData(configData)
    .build();

return kubernetesClient.resource(configMap).createOrReplace();

}
Environment:
•   Spring Boot Version: 3.1.4 JDK 21
•   Fabric8 Kubernetes Client Version: Gradle->io.fabric8:kubernetes-client:4.6.1
•   Minikube Version: v1.34.0
•   Kubernetes Version (in Minikube): Client Version: v1.31.1 Kustomize Version: v5.4.2

Observations:
•   The Spring Boot application connects to the Minikube cluster running locally.
•   Minikube is set up using the following Docker container:


    CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
5e189a09c71a   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.45   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   11 days ago   Up 11 days   127.0.0.1:53462->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:53463->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:53465->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:53466->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:53464->32443/tcp   minikube

Error Details:
Unfortunately, the error only occurs during the createOrReplace operation. It was working prior to the upgrade, and I suspect it might be due to changes in:
•   Spring Boot/Fabric8 client versions
•   Kubernetes API in the Minikube cluster
•   Minikube itself
•   During startup I do see Fabric8 kubernetes client able to find ~/.kube/config file

The exact error message is:
    2024-12-03T16:23:36.098Z  INFO 19728 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.m.h.service.CampEventService       : Status updated to=NOT_STARTED for camp id=1 was with the status=NOT_STARTED
2024-12-03T16:23:36.104Z ERROR 19728 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [ConfigMap]  with name: [config-1]  in namespace: [test-agents]  failed.] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751) ~[na:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:119) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:112) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:411) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:372) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:337) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:318) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:833) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:226) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:170) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.handlers.ConfigMapHandler.reload(ConfigMapHandler.java:63) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.handlers.ConfigMapHandler.reload(ConfigMapHandler.java:39) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableImpl.createOrReplace(NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableImpl.java:133) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableImpl.createOrReplace(NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableImpl.java:59) ~[kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.org.test.service.impl.KubernetesDeploymentServiceImpl.createOrReplaceConfigMap(KubernetesDeploymentServiceImpl.java:459) ~[main/:na]
        at com.org.test.service.impl.KubernetesDeploymentServiceImpl.createConfigMapForAgent(KubernetesDeploymentServiceImpl.java:394) ~[main/:na]
        at com.org.test.service.impl.KubernetesDeploymentServiceImpl.deployAgent(KubernetesDeploymentServiceImpl.java:128) ~[main/:na]
        at com.org.test.agent.KubernetesAgent.start(KubernetesAgent.java:22) ~[main/:na]
        at com.org.test.service.testService.startCamp(testService.java:362) ~[main/:na]
        at com.org.test.service.testService.processStartCamp(testService.java:350) ~[main/:na]
        at com.org.test.service.testService.startCamp(testService.java:171) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
       ...org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:128) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at ...org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

Questions:
1.  Are there any known compatibility issues with the versions mentioned?
2.  What additional debugging steps can I take to narrow down the root cause?
3.  Has the behavior of createOrReplace changed in recent Fabric8 or Kubernetes versions?

If you need more information, such as logs or specific configuration details, let me know. I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.

The issue was because of an older version of fabric8. Compatible version to resolve this issue is v7.0.0.
